# what should be the response content type for excel file

Tags: download, portlet, content-type, jsf-1.2

I am working in a jsf+ JBoss gatein based project. In one UI we have a download option as pdf and excel. In response for pdf , set content type as "application/pdf" , working fine .For excel I set it as "application/vnd.ms-excels" .It is working with MS excel. Is it enough for Open office and other spread-sheets?.Or is there any other generalized content type available?
(I have tried "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" but didnt work with MS-excel)

Answer (score 1):

application/vnd.ms-excel works with both excel and open office.